# Orange Data Mining: Change data type (e.g from continuous to discrete)

Tags: orange

I have loaded data in Orange using a CSV file, and some columns are being automatically detected as continuous (C) while in reality they're ordinal dicrete (i.e. may have integer values from 1 to 5).

I was expecting widgets such as the "Edit Domain Data" to let me change these meta attributes, but I couldn't figure it out. The only workaround I've managed so far was to save the CSV as a TAB file and add the meta attributes myself.

Am I missing something very silly? :)

Comment: Have you tried the Discretize widget? That's not quite the same as just telling it it should be a discrete variable, but it might help.

Comment: For those who are looking, see [Loading your Data](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/data/rst/index.html) to learn how to add the domains (continous/discrete) to your .tab formatted data.

Comment: It seems that Orange Data Mining doesn't have a GUI method to change the categorization from Continuous to Discrete. Currently, it seems, the only way to force a data variable (i.e. feature) to be Discrete (i.e. categorical) is by messing with the column headers [like so](http://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.org/loading-your-data/index.html#header-with-attribute-type-information).